# Observing incoming websocket messages with Reactive Extensions?

Tags: c#, linq, websocket, system.reactive

I want to use linq to process events received via a websocket connection. This is what I have so far:

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        string WsEndpoint = "wss://push.planetside2.com/streaming?environment=ps2&service-id=s:quicktesting";
        using (WebSocket ws = new WebSocket(WsEndpoint))
        {
            ws.OnMessage += Ws_OnMessage;

            ws.Connect();
            Console.ReadKey();
            ws.Close();
        }
    }

    private static void Ws_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
```

The first think that stumps me is how to turn `ws.OnMessage` into some sort of event stream. I cannot find any examples online for observing an *external* event source with reactive extensions. I intend to parse the messages into json objects, then filter and aggregate them.

Could someone provide an example of creating an observable from the websocket messages, and subscribing to it?

---

## Edit: Final Working Code

The only difference from the chosen answer is that I initialized the websocket before passing it into `Observable.Using`

```
//-------------------------------------------------------
// Create websocket connection
//-------------------------------------------------------
const string wsEndpoint = "wss://push.planetside2.com/streaming?environment=ps2&service-id=s:quicktesting";
WebSocket socket = new WebSocket(wsEndpoint);


//-------------------------------------------------------
// Create an observable by wrapping ws.OnMessage
//-------------------------------------------------------
var globalEventStream = Observable
    .Using(
        () => socket,
        ws =>
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern<EventHandler<MessageEventArgs>, MessageEventArgs>(
                    handler => ws.OnMessage += handler,
                    handler => ws.OnMessage -= handler));
//---------------------------------------------------------
// Subscribe to globalEventStream
//---------------------------------------------------------

IDisposable subscription = globalEventStream.Subscribe(ep =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Event Recieved");
    Console.WriteLine(ep.EventArgs.Data);
});

//----------------------------------------------------------
// Send message over websocket
//----------------------------------------------------------
socket.Connect();
socket.Send("test message");
// When finished, close the connection.
socket.Close();
```

Comment: What `WebSocket` library are you using?

Comment: I'm using `WebSocketSharp`

Comment: @mooglinux - Why have you got a `.Publish()` call? That will prevent all values until you call `.Connect()` on the observable. You probably can just remove `.Publish()`.

Comment: That was one of the things I was trying just to see what was up. Didn't work of course, so I'll update that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should set up your observable like this:

```
    var observable =
        Observable
            .Using(
                () => new WebSocket(WsEndpoint),
                ws =>
                    Observable
                        .FromEventPattern<EventHandler<MessageEventArgs>, MessageEventArgs>(
                            handler => ws.OnMessage += handler,
                            handler => ws.OnMessage -= handler));
```

This will correctly create the socket and then observe the event when the observable is subscribed to. When the subscription is disposed it will correctly detach from the event and dispose of the socket.

---

The type of `observable` will be `IObservable<EventPattern<MessageEventArgs>>`. You consume this observable in this way:

```
IDisposable subscription = observable.Subscribe(ep =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(ep.EventArgs.Data);
});
```

---

Thanks for posted the NuGet reference.

Here's the working code:

```
const string WsEndpoint = "wss://push.planetside2.com/streaming?environment=ps2&service-id=s:quicktesting";

Console.WriteLine("Defining Observable:");

IObservable<EventPattern<WebSocketSharp.MessageEventArgs>> observable =
    Observable
        .Using(
            () =>
            {
                var ws = new WebSocketSharp.WebSocket(WsEndpoint);
                ws.Connect();
                return ws;
            },
            ws =>
                Observable
                    .FromEventPattern<EventHandler<WebSocketSharp.MessageEventArgs>, WebSocketSharp.MessageEventArgs>(
                        handler => ws.OnMessage += handler,
                        handler => ws.OnMessage -= handler));

Console.WriteLine("Subscribing to Observable:");

IDisposable subscription = observable.Subscribe(ep =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Event Recieved");
    Console.WriteLine(ep.EventArgs.Data);
});

Console.WriteLine("Writing to Source:");

using (var source = new WebSocketSharp.WebSocket(WsEndpoint))
{
    source.Connect();
    source.Send("test");
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit to putting the websocket inside `Observable.Using` as opposed to the other answer?

Comment: When you dispose the observable's subscription, the socket gets disposed as well.

Comment: Do I write a custom function for `handler`? If so, what is the return type? I attempted to change `handler` to a function that printed the data and returned `void`, but that did not work.

Comment: @mooglinux - There is no need to change `handler` - in fact, if you do you are likely to break the code. I've added to the answer how to consume the observable.

Comment: Still not working. =/ 
I checked and my original version is still working, so it isn't a network issue. Will update my question with what I have now.

Comment: @mooglinux - I've tried to download WebSockets# to be able to actually run the code, but, even though I found it on NuGet, I can't find the exact library for the code you've presented. Can you tell me where to get it from?

Comment: Its a pre-release version, still on Nuget: 1.0.3-rc11

Comment: @mooglinux - Can you please let me know the NuGet id?

Comment: @Enigmativity Made one change, to allow me to send messages over the socket as well, and added to my post. 

THANK YOU for all the help!