# Show real time data using socket.io to a Win Form C#/VB client application

Tags: c#, socket.io

I'm using the following java script code as client to show real time data in my website

```
  const socket = io('https://mysocketio.com/', {
                timeout: 2000,
                forceNew: true,
                path: '/socket/',
                query: {
                    token: "AbcD"
                },
                transports: ['websocket'],
                reconnection: true
            });

            socket.on('connect', function () {
               alert('connected');
            });


            socket.on('change', function (liveData) {
               // live data processing

            });
            socket.on('disconnect', function () {
                alert('disconnect');
            });
```

The above code is working fine. Now my client wants to do the same in desktop application too. So please help me to show real time data in to desktop application using C# or VB as client code.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you asking for people to translate this to C#? Or whether there's web socket support in .NET? There is, through the [WebSocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocket?view=netcore-3.1) class

Comment: I'm new to win forms/socket programming. Im just want C# snippet for call socket.io into windows application using headers like above js code. Thanks.

Comment: SO isn't a translation service though, it's a Q&A site about specific programming problems. Have you tried writing anything? Have you tried using the WebSocket class? If you can't even create a desktop application, you won't be able to write the code that calls WebSocket. There are a *lot* of SO questions about WebSocket too

Comment: And a lot of SO questions about using socket.io specifically, that point to numerous socket.io clients in NuGet

Comment: I'm already created a windows app and I got an error. Thats why I asked this query. I raised another query regarding this please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62212272/how-to-get-real-time-data-using-socket-io-to-a-win-form-using-c-sharp).

Comment: Where's that code, what error? What library did you use? You won't get any answers for incomplete questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use web sockets with Reactive Extensions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112800/observing-incoming-websocket-messages-with-reactive-extensions) answer might be helpful.

Comment: For starters, this should be a comment as it doesn't actually answer the question. Second, the OP is actually asking for a translation from Java to C#. The code isn't event-based so simply using `async/await` would work

Comment: @Mohsen,  It's working perfectly.Thank you very much!.